# React Native - How to update screen on an already mounted component

Tags: react-native, react-props

I have 2 screens:

- Home Screen
- Login Screen

My entry point is my Home screen, if I am logged in (fetching datas), log out and then log in to another account. Since my Home component is already mounted, my data will not be updated and this.getDatas() will not be called again. I can't find solutions, I think I need to use "ComponentWillUpdate" in my Home.js to call this.getDatas() or something like that but you can't find the solution.

Here's my code:

Home.js

```
  componentDidMount = async () => {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    if (!await AsyncStorage.getItem('auth')) {
      navigation.navigate('Login');
    } else {
      this.getDatas();
    }
  }

  getDatas() {
    axios.get(`${apiUrl}/me`).then((res) => {
      this.setState({
        datas: res.data.datas,
      });
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.warn(err);
    });
  }
```

Login.js

```
export default class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: null,
      password: null,
    };
  }

  logIn() {
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    axios.post(`${apiUrl}/auth`, {
      email,
      password
    }).then((res) => {
      navigation.navigate('Home');
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.warn('Error:', err);
    });
  }
}
```

App.js

```
const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home,
  CreateGame,
  GamePreview,
  CardSelection,
  BonusCard,
  Game,
  GameResult
}, { initialRouteName: 'Home', headerMode: 'none', });

const LoginNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Login,
  Subscribe,
  SubscribeNext,
  ForgottenPassword,
}, { initialRouteName: 'Login', headerMode: 'none', });

const RootNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
  LoginNavigator,
  MainNavigator
}, { initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading' });

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <RootNavigator />;
  }
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: You should rethink your flow. The main screen should be `Login` and you'd store in `AsyncStorage` a token retrived from your backend. If there is a token, then `Login` screen should check token's validity and if everything is OK, then `Home` screen should be loaded else it will show the login form of `Login` screen.

Comment: I rethinked it by creating a LoaderView for entrypoint, which is going to check if my user is logged or not. But it doesn't resolve my problem. All about AsyncStorage for the token is already setted

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using **Switch Navigator** from `react-navigation` for your authentication flows in your application. So once you get logged out of your app and lands on login, the application screen pops out of the memory and thus when you login back, the `componentDidmount` will again be triggered.

Comment: I just tried Switch Navigator, but I've got the same result. The Home Screen is already mounted when I log in again

Comment: @tinmarfrutos Please specify the source in your question now.